# type of forwardRef function in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am making a HOC (higher order component) which helps in conditional rendering.

The code looks as below:

```
interface ConditionalProps {
  renderIf?: boolean
}
const ConditionalizeComponent = <Props,>(
  OriginalComponent: FC<Props>
): FC<Props & ConditionalProps> => {
  return (props) => {
    return <OriginalComponent {...props} />
  }
}

interface TestComponentProps
  extends DetailedHTMLProps<
    HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>,
    HTMLParagraphElement
  > {}

function BBB() {
  const TestComponent: FC<TestComponentProps> = ConditionalizeComponent(
    (props) => <p {...props} />
  )
  return <TestComponent renderIf={true} />
}
```

This code seems to work perfectly,

Now I want to forward any ref I receive down to the `OriginalComponent`, for that I am using the react function `forwardRef()`.

Here's the same code above, but instead of returning a regular function at the end (regular function = I mean function component), I am returning a forwardRef:

```
interface ConditionalProps {
  renderIf?: boolean
}
const ConditionalizeComponent = <Props,>(
  OriginalComponent: FC<Props>
): FC<Props & ConditionalProps> => {
  return forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return <OriginalComponent {...props} ref={ref} />
  })
}

interface TestComponentProps
  extends DetailedHTMLProps<
    HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>,
    HTMLParagraphElement
  > {}

function BBB() {
  const TestComponent: FC<TestComponentProps> = ConditionalizeComponent(
    (props) => <p {...props} />
  )
  return <TestComponent renderIf={true} />
}
```

However, Typescript doesn't like this, It's complaining, and saying the following ***very*** long error:

```
Type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<Props & ConditionalProps> & RefAttributes<unknown>>' is not assignable to type 'FC<Props & ConditionalProps>'.
  Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
    Type 'WeakValidationMap<PropsWithoutRef<Props & ConditionalProps> & RefAttributes<unknown>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<Props & ConditionalProps> | undefined'.
      Type 'WeakValidationMap<PropsWithoutRef<Props & ConditionalProps> & RefAttributes<unknown>>' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<Props & ConditionalProps>'.
        Type 'keyof Props | "renderIf"' is not assignable to type 'keyof PropsWithoutRef<Props & ConditionalProps> | keyof RefAttributes<unknown>'.
          Type 'keyof Props' is not assignable to type 'keyof PropsWithoutRef<Props & ConditionalProps> | keyof RefAttributes<unknown>'.
            Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'keyof PropsWithoutRef<Props & ConditionalProps> | keyof RefAttributes<unknown>'.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof PropsWithoutRef<Props & ConditionalProps> | keyof RefAttributes<unknown>'.ts(2322)
```

I am wondering, what's wrong in my code, or what is the return type of the forwardRef, or how to use it.

Comment: Did you try to pass generic arguments to `forwardRef` function, like `forwardRef<HTMLElement, ConditionalProps>()`?

Comment: @tymzap, I'm not sure, I'm still new to typescript, and I'm finding it too complex to estimate the correct types that I should export from React to use

Answer (score 0):

React forwardRef is a method that allows parent components pass down (i.e., “forward”) refs to their children. Using forwardRef in React gives the child component a reference to a DOM element created by its parent component. This then allows the child to read and modify that element anywhere it is being used

Comment: ok thanks, but what is the solution in typescript then